# How to set automatic scaling in Google Cloud Managed VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-managed-vm

We are plannig deploy our app on google cloud managed VM. I tried to use automatic scaling. I have changed following parameters as per this doc

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/java/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml

This is our app.yaml file settings

```
runtime: java
vm: true
threadsafe: true

automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: 1
  max_idle_instances: 5  # default value
  min_pending_latency: 30ms  # default value
  max_pending_latency: 1000
  max_concurrent_requests: 50

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: this field is required, but ignored
  secure: always
```

But when I tried to deploy we are getting following errors

```
"description": "VM-based automatic scaling should NOT have the following parameter(s): [min_idle_instances, min_pending_latency,max_idle_instances,max_pending_latency ]",
           "field": "version.automatic_scaling"
```

how to set max,min idle instances number , latency and how to set version number in app.yaml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry!  That's a documentation bug (we're fixing it).  Automatic scaling is actually enabled on your module by default - you don't need to add any configuration at all to use it.  The min_idle_instances and min_pending_latency fields are not supported by Managed VMs.  In most cases, you don't need to add any config here at all for autoscaling, it should all 'just work'.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. You saved my day.

Comment: but atleast we should have control of max_idle_instances, can we enable that.

Comment: It's over a year later and this "documentation bug" still exists. Further, when I tried to report it I was told I would need to enroll in the premium support package.

Comment: It should all 'just work' but it starts counting from 2 instances.. why the hell ?

Comment: Flex will run any version of node that you like!  You can create a `Dockerfile` with your app, and set `runtime: custom` (I think ...).

Comment: @JustinBeckwith this bug still exists; Also how do we set no idle instances?